# Changing connection string of windows service while installing with setup installer

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services, connection-string

I have two projects in my solution. One is an application. The other is a Windows service. I created a setup installer and added the primary output of these two projects to the installer. My setup installer asks for a data source while installing the application and the Windows service. After inputting the SQL server name the both application and the Windows service will be installed on the system. I am able to open and use the application with the changed connection string, but when I check the Windows service status it is not in a running state. When I try to start the Windows service manually I get

> error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request into timely fashion".

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the connection string for the service stored?

Comment: In the Servicename.exe.config file

Comment: Finally I am able to change connection string of the windows service while installing the windows service with the setup installer.I have overrided the BeforeInstall() method of the installer class then changed the connection string of the windows service and installed it to the system it is working fine and running.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find some clues in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Yes i checked the Event viewer but it is not showing my service and any errors related with it. What should i do to log errors in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the right config file ?for Windows Services the config file have to be on the same folder of .exe file and need to have the same name, for example MyService.exe and MyService.config

Comment: Yes I am changing the right config file. But still the service is not starting. If i put correct data source in the connection string and not change it while installing the service will get installed correctly and is running automatically. But in case of changing it at installing it does not start.